# numeric or value error on the procedure I've been calling in java

Tags: java, sql, oracle

When I'm calling the procedure in java in my callable statement it says that I have a numeric or value error in my code. Yet, when I've tried to run the SQL file alone on oracle database it works fine. There are numeric or value error appearing on it and the result that I need comes out perfectly fine. So I don't understand why whenever that procedure is called in my java class it keeps on saying that error. I tried to locate the line where the so-called error is and here it is...

Here's the code for my procedure

```
CREATE OR REPLACE
PROCEDURE RENTING
(P_NNAME IN VARCHAR2,
P_ADD IN VARCHAR2,
P_PHONE IN NUMBER,
P_ORDER IN VARCHAR2,
P_EMP_ID IN NUMBER,
P_VALID OUT NUMBER,
P_OR_NO OUT NUMBER
)
IS
V_AVAI  TITLE.AVAILABLE%TYPE;
P_OR VARCHAR2(5000);
P_OR_2 VARCHAR2(5000);
ORD_NO NUMBER(6);
TID NUMBER(38);
NUM NUMBER(3);
CTR NUMBER(3);
GO NUMBER(1);
BEGIN
P_OR:=P_ORDER;
ORD_NO:=SEQ_ORDER_NO.NEXTVAL;

INSERT INTO TRANSACTIONS (ORDER_NO, CUST_NICKNAME, CUST_ADD, CUST_CONTACT)
VALUES (ORD_NO, P_NNAME, P_ADD, P_PHONE);

INSERT INTO RENTS (ORDER_NO,ORDERS,DATERENTED,EMP_ID,DATERETURNED)
VALUES (ORD_NO,P_OR,SYSDATE,P_EMP_ID,NULL);

LOOP
  CTR:=INSTR(P_OR,';');
  NUM:=LENGTH(P_OR);
  IF CTR!=0 THEN
    CTR:=CTR-1;
    P_OR_2:=SUBSTR(P_OR,1,CTR);
    TID:=TO_NUMBER(P_OR_2);        //here's the part of the conversion that is wrong in java
    CTR:=CTR+2;
    P_OR:=SUBSTR(P_OR,CTR,NUM);
    SELECT AVAILABLE 
    INTO V_AVAI
    FROM TITLE
    WHERE TITLE_ID=TID;
    IF V_AVAI!=0 THEN
      UP(TID);
      P_VALID:=1;
    ELSIF V_AVAI=0 THEN
      P_VALID:=0;
    END IF;
  ELSIF CTR = 0 THEN
    P_OR_2:=SUBSTR(P_OR,1,NUM);
    TID:=TO_NUMBER(P_OR_2);
    SELECT AVAILABLE 
    INTO V_AVAI
    FROM TITLE
    WHERE TITLE_ID=TID;
    IF V_AVAI!=0 THEN
      UP(TID);
      P_VALID:=1;
      P_OR_NO:=ORD_NO;
    ELSIF V_AVAI=0 THEN
      P_VALID:=0;
    END IF;
    GO:=1;
  END IF;
  EXIT WHEN GO=1;
END LOOP;
END RENTING;
/
```

Comment: You should also post the Java code that tries to call your stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

Run the program in the debugger and evaluate the arguments.
Perhaps you're trying to put a string that can not be converted into a NUMBER.